# Is there a way to see the raw SQL that a Sequel expression will generate?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Say I have a Sequel expression like:

```
db.select(:id).from(:some_table).where(:foo => 5)
```

Is there a way to get the SQL string that this will generate (i.e. `"SELECT id FROM some_table WHERE foo = 5"`)? I notice that calling `inspect` or `to_s` on the result of the above expression includes that generated SQL, but not sure how to access it directly.

And how about Sequel expressions that do not return a dataset, like:

```
db.from(:some_table).update(:foo => 5)
```

Is it possible to see the SQL from this before it's executed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can call `sql` on dataset:

```
db.select(:id).from(:some_table).where(:foo => 5).sql # => "SELECT `id` FROM `some_table` WHERE (`foo` = 5)"
```

For update queries you can do this:

```
db.from(:some_table).update_sql(:foo => 5) # => "UPDATE `some_table` SET `foo` = 5"
```

Some similar useful methods:

```
insert_sql
delete_sql
truncate_sql
```

Comment: What is `db` in this case and how do you access/instantiate it?

Comment: Is there anyway to get at this from an ActiveRecord Relation?

Comment: It's a Sequel connnection like `db = Sequel.connect('sqlite://blog.db')`. In `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you can just call `to_sql`

Comment: Thanks. :-) In the case of a particular Rails expression requiring multiple SQL statements to execute, do you know if `.to_sql` just gives the latest?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It will show you the statement related to the relation you call it on (it will show joins etc but not includes and preloads).

Comment: I'm not sure I know what I mean either, perhaps because I don't know what an include or preload is in this context. ;-) Is it sometimes necessary for Rails to execute a query in order to even construct a relation? I'm trying to understand the paragraphs starting with "Please note" at http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-explain/

Comment: Is there a known way to do this for distinct? For example `db[:table].distinct(:id).sql` and `db[:table].distinct_sql(:id)` don't work.